# JOIN two relations in SQL without using JOIN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a `users` table and a `books` table. Two tables have a pretty standard One-to-Many relationship. Their data and structure are as follow:

`users` table: 
[image]

`books` table: 
[image]

To get the information of what books does each user have, I would normally do a standard `JOIN` query:

```
SELECT * FROM users JOIN books ON users.id = books.user_id
```

At the same time, I came across with another query, that seems to do the same work, which writes as:

```
SELECT * FROM users, books WHERE users.id = books.id
```

These two queries seems to give the exactly same result as follow
[image]

The second query without the `JOIN` clause I see in one of Standford's online courses and it seems to work fine. However I was taught to use, and saw other developers using the `JOIN` as the approach to this type of relationship. My questions are:

1. Are those two queries equivalent in terms of the query result?
2. Is there a reason why we should use one over the other?
3. Do the SQL engine perform different when executing these two ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Comment: (Clearly,) This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in a post ask exactly 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please in code questions give a [mre]--obligatory if debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Result:**

Both the queries would definitely give you the same result

**2. Which is better**

It is recommended to use the first one. Because it is safer in many ways. For instance, if we have to perform `INNER JOIN`, using the second syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users, books 
WHERE users.id = books.id
```

If you forgot the `WHERE users.id = books.id`, the query `won't fail`. But it will return a `cross join` and we may not notice this error.

However, using the first syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
JOIN books ON users.id = books.user_id
```

If we forget the `ON` condition, we will get a `syntax error`. Moreover, doing a `CROSS JOIN` will be very comprehensive in first syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM users CROSS JOIN books
```

Than the second syntax.

Refer this [Blog](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

**3. Performance:**

As far as I'm aware, there is no performance difference between both the queries

**Additional info:**

The difference between the two queries is the `JOIN` syntax:

- The first one use the `ANSI-92` JOIN syntax.
- The second one use the old `ANSI-89` JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I would say there is no difference between the two queries besides readability. Since you are joining two tables here it makes more sense to use join instead of where clause.